# How to implement back button in Angular for navigating previous page?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I have a `list-component` where I want to keep the `pageIndex` value by setting some variables in another class just before navigating to another component let's say `x-component`. Then, when navigating back to the `list-component`, I want to get the previously set `pageIndex` so that open that page instead of opening the first page on the datatable. So, what is an alegant way to fix this problem without using a service or subcribtion? I can use another class, but not a service. I tried to retrieve the set values from a class, but `pageIndex` value is undefined when trying to retrieve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also have the `pageIndex` as a URL param of the page where `list-component` is rendered.

Inject in your ctor:

```
private route: ActivatedRoute
```

Then in your `ngOnInit` do something like:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
    if (params.pageIndex) {
        this.pageIndex = params.pageIndex;
    }
});
```

In your routing module your URL should match: `some-url/:pageIndex`. And when paging back and forth in the list the URL should be updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure where should I apply these code blocks. Do you mean that to pass all the parameters to the `x-component` and subscribe route parameters in `list-component`?

Comment: @Fredrick no you don't need to pass parameters to `x-component` because when you navigate back, the above subscription to the URL params will make sure the `pageIndex` gets the last value instead of resetting to first page.

Comment: Thanks, but where should I set `pageIndex` parameter? When I set that parameter in the list component and then I am not sure if I should pass back some other parameters from details component. I use `this._location.back();` to navigate back without passsing any parameter.

Comment: On the other hand I am wondering that instead of passing the parameters from list to details and then pass again from details to list, **would it be better** to save these parameters in the list component (maybe via a class) and then retrieve them onInit method of the list without making any modification on the details component?

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot for your valuable helps and voted up ;)

Comment: @Fredrick the `pageIndex` is in the URL so when returning from the details page (component) by calling `location.back()`, `list-component` will parse the URL (as my code above demonstrates), and do the magic. Therefore the details page does not need to receive/send any parameters.

Comment: This time is ok. But I think the parameters will be seen on the address bar I think. Is that true? I am avoiding that and pass the parameters. Is that possible in your approach?

Comment: @Fredrick yes URL = address bar. Why avoid? One plus of includnig it in the URL is that if you refresh the page you will get the right `pageIndex`. Otherwise it will reset. The URL helps you save the state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226275/discussion-between-benny-and-fredrick).

Comment: What about the `back()` method in Details page? How  should I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sessionStorage`.

In `x-component`, save `pageIndex` with this.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('pageIndex', pageIndex);
```

Then load this value in `list-component` like this.

```
public pageIndex = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('pageIndex') ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

previousUrl: string;
constructor(private location: Location,private router: Router){ }

goBackFunction(){
router.events
.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
.subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {

      console.log('prev:', event.url);
      this.previousUrl = event.url;
});

 this.location.back()  
}
```

It will take you to the previous page :)

Comment: What about getting the parameters that were set previously in the `list-component`?

Comment: @Fredrick I've edit with some new code, check them

Comment: I think there is a misunderstooding. There are 2 components and I have some parameters in the list component. Then navigate to details component. And when coming back to the list page again, I need to get the previously set parameters. But you just gave an implementation  on the details component to come back without any parameter restore.

Comment: Beware that there's an edge case with this scenario such that if user opens a new tab there won't be an entry in the history to go back to. This can throw user out of the Angular application as well as introduce security issues as there's no API for directly inspecting the browser history.