# What is a proper way to preserve parameters after navigating back?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, session, components

In my Angular app, I have list and details pages and I want to lkeep the `pageIndex` value before navigating to details page. There is a Back button in the details page and I can return the list page by clicking on that button. However, I want to get the `pageIndex` value when navigating back to the list page and let the user open the page where he/she was before. For example I navigate 3rd page on the list and click details. At this stage I set the `pageIndex` to 3 and then navigate to details. Then by clicking the Back button I can navigate back to the list page, but I need to retrieve the `pageIndex` as 3.

So, what is an elegant way to fix this problem in Angular 10+?

***list-componnet***

```
details(id) {
    this.router.navigate(['/details'], { state: { id: id } }); // I pass id value of the record
}
```

***details-componnet***

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.id = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.id;
}

back() {
    this._location.back();
}
```

Comment: Do not call _location.back(), you need to add a route parameter for list-component like pageIndex,  and use angular router navigate this.router.navigate(['/list'], {pageIndex: xxx})

Comment: Or you can use sessionStorage to store the value of pageIndex, and then in ngOnInit func to retrieve the pageIndex.

Comment: @KevinZhang **1.** Why should I avoid uisng `_location.back()`?

Comment: @KevinZhang **2.** Could you please post an answer for `route parameter` and `sessionStorage` scenario? Actually I already pass id parameter (`state: { id: id }`) and I think I can add pageIndex to that parameters. But what about the passing them back and rouring.module changes? Could you give an example by referring list and details page?

Comment: If i am not understand wrong, the pageIndex you mentioned is a page for your data-table in list component? If it is, when you use _location.back(), browser will redirect to last history record, the browser history record will not have this information, so you need to retriveve pageIndex from router or sessionStorege or others.

Comment: The id is for your detail component, you need to add a router parametern for your list component too.

Comment: Yes,  the pageIndex you mentioned is a page for your data-table in list component. But could you pls post an example by giving the routing.module parameters? I tried this approach but failed to make it work.

Comment: On the other hand, what about the other options? **`sessionStorage`** and using a dedicated service or class?

Comment: I have posted an answer that uses the `sessionStorage` in your [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65398669/how-to-implement-back-button-in-angular-for-navigating-previous-page/65402498#65402498). Did you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a simple example to make it work, I use the sessionStorage and router together, use router to show your the routing module, actually you can just use sessionStorage only, and wrapper it in a servive. Then you can retrieve the pageIndex anywhere.

And if you want to use router only, the pageIndex paramater will be place in both list and detail component, since this two component all need to use this value, in list component you will need pageIndex to set data-table, in detail component you need this value to pass to list component when redirect back triggered.

The routing module like below:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { ListComponent } from "./list/list.component";
import { DetailComponent } from "./detail/detail.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "list", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "list/:pageIndex=1",
    component: ListComponent,
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: "detail/:id",
    component: DetailComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Here you can navigate to list page from detail page use:

```
this.router.navigate(["/list/" + pageIndex]);
```

And then in list page's ngOnInit method to set current pageIndex to your data-table. Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5vmteg?file=src/app/list/list.component.ts

Comment: PS: I used the data-table in ngx-pluto package, this is the package I wrote before.~_~

Answer (score 1):

Use `sessionStorage`, a `listService` or router `queryParams` to keep track of the current `pageIndex`.
I´d advocate for `queryParams` as it seems most logical and you can also link directly to specific page.

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }
```

```
// Access the queryParam in list component
// Ie /list?pageIndex=4
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        // Do something with params.pageIndex if it exists
    }
);
```

I´d also consider to change the way you handle routing to the details. If the route to the list is `/list` then route to the details should be `/list/<listid>` so you can link directly to the details if needed.

You can access the listId parameter as below but note it must also be specified as parameter in the router definition.

```
// Router definition
{ path: 'list/', component: ListComponent},
{ path: 'list/:listId', component: ListIdComponent}
```

```
// Access the listId in the details component
this.route.params.subscribe(param=> {
    // Do somthing with param.listId
});
```